# How does one perform a "range query"?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

Google cloud dataflow supports  what I would call a "full outer join" SQL  like statement through their "CoGroupByKey"method. However, is there any way to implement in dataflow what would be in SQL a "range join"? For example, if I had a table called "people" in which there was a floating point field called "age". And let's say I wanted all the pairs of people in which their ages were within say five years from each other. I could write the following statement:

select p1.name, p1.age, p2.name, p2.age
from people p1, people p2
where p1.age between (p2.age - 5.0) and (p2.age + 5.0);

I couldn't determine if there was a way to accomplish this in dataflow. (Again, if I wanted a strict equality, that I could use a CoGroupByKey,  but in this case it's not a strict equality condition).

For my particular use case, the "people" table is not too large – maybe 500,000 rows and approximately 50 megs of RAM required. So, I could, I think, simply run a asList() method to create a single object that sits in a single computer's RAM and then just sort the people object by age and then write some sort of routine that "walks through the list from the low stage to the highest age" and  while walking through the list outputs those people whose ages are less than 10 years from each other. This would work, but it would be single threaded etc. I was wondering if there was a "better" way of doing it using the dataflow architecture. (And other developers may need to find a "dataflow" way of doing  this operation if the object that they were dealing with dies not fit nicely into memory of one single computer, e.g. a people table of maybe 1 billion rows etc.)

Answer (score 1):

The trick to making this work efficiently at scale is to partition your data into sets of potential matches.  In your case, you could assign each person to two different keys, age rounded up to multiple of 5, and age rounded down to multiple of 5.  Then, do a GroupByKey on these buckets, and emit all the pairs within each bucket that are actually close enough in age.  You'll need to eliminate duplicates, since it's possible for two records to both end up in the same two buckets.

With this solution, the entire data does not need to fit in memory, just each subset of the data.